# intellij how to avoid the intellij reset the custom maven configuration(home directory, setting file...) to default

Tags: intellij-idea

When I reopen the intellij, I found the maven configuration reset to the default every time. Please let me know how to keep the my configuration.

Comment: what maven configuration are you stating here?

Comment: my custom configuration, maven home directory, Usr setting file, local repository.

Comment: Got the same issue: when I reopen IntelliJ 2018.3, my Maven home directory is reset to the default one "Bundled (Maven 3)". Same for User settings file.